# there is an error is custom_scaffold.dart after adding custom navigator. there error in the file is shown below

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Yys.png)the assertion of custom_scaffold has failed i dont know for what reason all the indexing are correct in my point of view.  the code which have written is. the material library is included in the code. is there any mistake that i am doing? kindly help me its quite irritating This is my code. i am not able to fix it. have tried everything but this error wont go.

ERROR:

```
EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building BottomBar(dirty, state: _BottomBarState#21af2):
Assertion failed:
file:///Users/ASM/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/custom_navigator-0.3.0/lib/custom_scaffold.dart:33:9
../…/lib/custom_scaffold.dart:33
(scaffold.bottomNavigationBar as BottomNavigationBar)
            .items
            .length ==
            children.length
"[BottomNavigationBar] and `children` should be the same size"
The relevant error-causing widget was:
BottomBar
lib/main.dart:39
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

My code:  categoryscreen.dart

```
    import 'package:custom_bottom_navigation_bar/custom_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
    import 'package:custom_navigation_bar/custom_navigation_bar.dart';
    import 'package:custom_navigator/custom_scaffold.dart';
    import 'package:custom_navigator/custom_navigator.dart';
    import 'package:my_fapp/styles/categoryscreenstyles.dart';



    class CategoryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CategoryScreenState createState() => _CategoryScreenState();
    }

    class _CategoryScreenState extends State<CategoryScreen> {
      AppBar buildAppBar() {
        return AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Welcome",
            style: CategoryScreenStyle.categoryTitleStyles,
          ),
          actions: [
            RotationTransition(
              turns: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(90 / 360),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  SvgImages.filter,
                  color: AppColors.baseBlackColor,
                  width: 35,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                SvgImages.search,
                color: AppColors.baseBlackColor,
                width: 35,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(
            indicator: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
            unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.baseBlackColor,
            labelColor: AppColors.baseDarkPinkColor,
            automaticIndicatorColorAdjustment: false,
            tabs: [
              Text("All"),
              Text("Men"),
              Text("Woman"),
              Text("Kids"),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: AppColors.baseWhiteColor,
            appBar: buildAppBar(),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                //All Place
                CategoryAllTabBar(),
                //Men  Place
                CategoryMenTabBar(
                  categoryProductModel: menCategoryData,
                ),
                //woman Place
                CategoryMenTabBar(
                  categoryProductModel: womenCategoryData,
                ),
                //Kids place
                CategoryMenTabBar(
                  categoryProductModel: forKids,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

```
    class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with BottomBar.
class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Homepage(),
    CategoryScreen(),
    // YourBagScreen(),
    // WishListScreen(),
    // ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScaffold(
      children: _widgetOptions,
      onItemTap: _onItemTapped,
      scaffold: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          unselectedFontSize: 0.0,
          selectedFontSize: 0.0,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          unselectedItemColor: AppColors.baseGrey40Color,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.grid_view),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
              label: '',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: '',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: AppColors.baseDarkPinkColor,
          ),
          // selectedItemColor: AppColors.baseDarkPinkColor,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] you question to include your `BottomNavigationBar`

Comment: try to replace all widget(CategoryAllTabBar) `children` . it might be coming from `CategoryAllTabBar`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh did not understand sorry

Comment: @MendelG Attached

Comment: tried removing the bottom bar but the error still remains it. the error is coming from the bottombar.dart> CustomScaffold > "child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),"